# Difference between onLongPress and onShowPress

Tags: android, motionevent, gesturedetector

According to Android Developers:

> `onLongPress` Notified when a long press occurs with the initial on
>   down MotionEvent that trigged it.
>
> `onShowPress` The user has performed a down MotionEvent and not performed a move or
>   up yet. This event is commonly used to provide visual feedback to the
>   user to let them know that their action has been recognized i.e.
>   highlight an element.

I tried both with a button and used a `Toast` to indicate that `showPress` and `longPress` happened. However, I don't see any difference.

What's the difference between `onLongPress` and `onShowPress`? What are some examples when we `override` `GestureDetector` for those `MotionEvents`?

Comment: they are sent at different times: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java#620 - see also line #628

Comment: No Toasts(). Highlight an element. Give the font of the button a color.

Comment: @pskink Would you mind providing a full answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onLongPress` will be triggered the moment the amount of time a touch event (pressing the screen) is equal to `getLongPressTimeout` (can be seen [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getLongPressTimeout())). When it triggers, this shows that a press has turnt to a long press.

`onShowPress`, on the other hand, indicates that a touch event is indeed a tap (not a scroll). To know when a touch event is a tap, there is a time interval in which movement from the touch event will be registered. The time interval is returned by `getTapTimeout` (read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getTapTimeout())).

Both are related to touch events, but have different time of trigger (and different purposes). Reading the link provided by the comment in the question ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java#620)) will help you in understanding both.